# Helping me my study of introduction to analysis

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

I am a math major student who started study math now In my university class , my professor proposed me a few question and I thoought several hours but I can`t write logically so i ask about question because I have no enough time I post my all question at a one time sorry^^
 1.Are the empty set and singleton sets connected or not?
 2.Explain why the space R n   is connected
 3.Prove that a region is connected
 4.Prove that the intervals are only the only connected subsets of R 1

and I want to hear some advise of study of introduction analysis^^ have a nice day I really really appreciate for your help to solve these problem!
I need help.. I understand definition but since I was beginner .. I have some difficulty to write down the proof exactly. so I asking these question again!
If possible, I want to know exact proof.